# Sequential (not parallel) async sql queries javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

what I'm trying to do is execute a second query from mssql using the result of a first query also from sql, even using the await operator the first query executes correctly and shows the value, but the second doesn't even execute

obs: I'm using npm's mssql-async library

```
const row = await db.getrow(
      "SELECT [_TURN_TYPE],[_IDENTIFICATION] FROM _HANDSON_STATIONS WHERE _DESCRIPTION = @desc",
      {
        desc: "Montagem Motor de Partida",
      }
    );

    console.log(row);

    const stationId = row._IDENTIFICATION;
    const turnType = row._TURN_TYPE;

    const row1 = await db.getrow(
      "SELECT * FROM [_HANDSON_PRODUCTION_DATA] where _DATE = @date AND [_STATION_ID] = @station AND _TURN = @turn ORDER BY _INDEX ASC",
      {
        date: dateFormat,
        station: stationId,
        turn: turnType,
      }
    );
    console.log(row1);
```

Comment: *"but the second doesn't even execute"* - Then what does happen?  Is an error thrown?  Is that last `console.log` statement invoked?  When you step through this in a debugger, what specifically happens?

Comment: @David I debugged the code and saw that it executes, but the await operator doesn't work for the second "row1" function, it returns a pending Promise even using await

Comment: Where/how specifically are you observing this?  What specifically is `db.getrow` and where is it defined?

Comment: @PatrickSampaio can you share the rest of the code? is this snippet of code wrapped inside an async function? is there a try/catch for handling errors? are you getting any errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.